# JPQL: SELECT b, count(ts) FROM Branch b JOIN b.tourScheduleList WHERE ts.deleted = 0

Tags: jpql

I get the desired result here

```
SELECT b, count(ts) FROM Branch b JOIN b.tourScheduleList ts WHERE ts.deleted =  0 GROUP BY b.id ORDER BY b.name ASC

b1 | 2
b2 | 1
```

but then I need to get the count of `ts.tourAppliedList` so I updated the query to

```
SELECT b, count(ts), count(ta) FROM Branch b JOIN b.tourScheduleList ts JOIN ts.tourAppliedList ta WHERE ts.deleted =  0 GROUP BY b.id ORDER BY b.name ASC
```

which resulted to

```
b1 | 3 | 3
b2 | 2 | 2
```

the result is wrong. I don't know why `count(ts)` is equal to `count(ta)`

I tried returning `ts` then just do a count later but it's returning all its content without considering the `ts.deleted = 0`

```
SELECT b, ts FROM Branch b JOIN b.tourScheduleList ts WHERE ts.deleted =  0 GROUP BY b.id ORDER BY b.name ASC
```

then in the view I just `#{item.ts.tourAppliedList.size()}` it's not considering the `ts.deleted = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your expectation is wrong.
This Join will give you:

```
b1 | ts1 | ta1
b1 | ts1 | ta2
b1 | ts2 | ta3
b2 | ts3 | ta4
b2 | ts3 | ta5
```

Or something along this line...
What happens when you group and count those rows?
Simple you have 3 entry for b1 and 2 for b2.
What you need there is `count(distinct ts)`
Since there are multiple ts for every different ta you would then find a difference

P.s. i dont know if jpql permit a count(distinct ), if thats the case you better do two query and count ts with the join only on ts and then ta with the join on ts and ta

Comment: yeah, my expectation was wrong. i had to do subquery